# How to increase number of messages retrieved on a Discord channel (python)

Tags: python, python-requests, discord

With following code, I am able to retrieve messages from a given Discord channel, but only the 50 last messages get retrieved.
Please, how to increase this number (for instance 200 messages)?
Thanks for your help.
Have a good day,
Bests,

```py
import requests
import json

def retrieve_messages(channelIdn author):
    headers = {'authorization':author}
    r = requests.get(f'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages', headers=headers)
    return json.loads(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the limit is 100 messages according to the docs. You can set that amount up to 100 by adding the limit query string param.

ex: `https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channelId}/messages?limit={limit}`

Source: https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see I can do pagination and get previous messages thanks to 'before'.